# Get object from thymeleaf to js

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a `for:each` like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="bill : ${bills}" id="bill">
        <td th:text="${bill.bill_id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${bill.client.phone}"></td>
        <td th:text="${bill.date}"></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" id="open-modal">Ver detalles</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The question is how can i get the entire `${bill}` to a variable in js or jquery because i need more information, i saw the documentation and it said:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    ...

    var user  name = /*[[${bill}]]*/ '';

    ...
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

but i have tried this on a external js file and does not work , so i need 1 solution for this.

[imagen del error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzja6.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have `${bills}` as  a javascript object, try this

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

    var bills = [[${bills}]];  //Make sure this is bills and not bill as you have done it.
    console.log(bills);

/*]]>*/
</script>
```